# header background and another one to repeat on Wordpress sandbox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sandbox, repeat

im building off the wordpress plaintxt sandbox theme, and what i have i a big background picture, on the body element, which is basically the whole background, it doesnt repeat.
what i want is to have another jpg to repeat at the end of this one.

from what i realize, i cant put them on the same element.
i tried to put the repeatable one on the html element but it didnt work correctly.

what is the correct way to achieve this??

thanks,
adir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 now comes with multiple backgrounds. You can view the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image).

An example of using this would be:

```
body {
    background-image: url(pic1.jpg) top left no-repeat, 
                      url(pic2.jpg) bottom left repeat;
}
```

Enjoy!